# Two dependent drop-down lists with the values in two different tables

Tags: php, yii

I need to show two dependent drop-down lists in my page. If we select an item from first drop-down list, based on the item which we selected, it should filter the entries in the second drop-down list, then I need to perform a search using the value in the second drop-down list. But the thing is that the values come from the table to show in the first drop-down list is not an active record of it. Can anyone help on this?

Currently I have that second drop-down list in place and it can perform a search based on the selected value. Now what I need to do is place a drop-down list above this and filter the items based on the first drop-down list.

### Edit

1st table - client_id, client_name - items in the first drop-down list should show client names

2nd table - program_id, client_id,  program_name -

3rd table - ad_id, program_id, ad_name - the second drop-down list should show ad_names filtered by using client_id.

Comment: What data structure do you have the values for the 1st dropdown?  You should be able to make this into a usable format to pass to [CHtml::listOptions()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listOptions-detail), which you can then pass on to [CHtml::activeDropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail)

Comment: How did you get the values for the second dropdown?  Do the same for the first, and use listOptions as your data source for your drop down

Comment: there is a small change in my requirement, i have added that in the edit, please take a look at it

Comment: Okay, so why aren't you using a model for this?  All three tables can be related in a model, and your dropdowns can be easily populated this way.  Or is your question how to configure a model?

Comment: the active record related to my view is only that 3rd table, so in that case how can i access the 1st table? yes, i do have models for all the 3 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did that, here is it.

In my controller,

```
public function actionDynamicDropdownList()
   {
    if($_POST['client_id'] > '0') {
        $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('program_id, program_name')->from('program')->where('client_id='.$_POST['client_id'].'')->order('program_name')->queryAll();
        $this->render('admin', array(
            'result' => $result,
        ));
      }
}
public function actionDynamicProgramsList()
{
    if($_POST['program_id'] > '0') {
        $results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('ad_id, ad_name')->from('ads')->where('program_id='.$_POST['program_id'].'')->order('ad_name')->queryAll();
        $this->render('admin', array(
            'results' => $results,
        ));
    }
}
```

and in my view, I have added

```
<?php
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('client_id, client_name')->from('client')->order('client_name')->queryAll();
echo CHtml::dropDownList('client_id', '',CHtml::listData($data,'client_id','client_name'), array(
'empty'=>'- Select Client Name -',
'ajax'=> array(
'type'=>'POST',
'url'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php?r=page/dynamicDropdownList',
'update'=>'#program_id'))); 

//empty since it will be filled by the above dropdown
echo CHtml::dropDownList('program_id','', CHtml::listData($result,'program_id','program_name'), array(
'empty'=>'- Select Program Name - ',
'onchange'=>'alert(this.value);',
'ajax'=> array(
'type'=>'POST',
'url'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php?r=page/dynamicProgramsList',
'update'=>'#ad_id')));
    //empty since it will be filled by the above dropdown
echo CHtml::dropDownList('ad_id','', CHtml::listData($results,'ad_id','ad_name'), array(
'empty'=>'- Select Ad Name - ',

));
?>
```